# Why do I get the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Response' in my SMS app that interfaces with Twilio?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, ngrok, pyenv

Also in ngrok, there appears an internal server error 500 when attempting to make a post request using twilio.

Here is the section of my code where I feel there is a problem with:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio import twiml
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia

app = Flask(__name__)

wolf = wolframalpha.Client(wolfram_app_id)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sms():

    message_body = request.form['Body']
    resp = twiml.Response()

    replyText = getReply(message_body) 
    resp.message('Hi\n\n' + replyText )
    return str(resp)
```

I have updated all latest versions of ngrok, python, twilio and Flask.
I also followed all the steps to activate the virtualenv.

Comment: Can you try running `which python`? The [Make: project](http://makezine.com/projects/sms-bot/) you're following says it doesn't matter what version of Python you're using, but I have a feeling it needs to be 2.7 according to the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/twiml/say-response#let-twilio-find-your-server). (I believe the `twiml.Response()` might not be supported in Python3, and you seem to say your Python is of the latest version, so that might be a conflict).

Comment: I actually rerun the program using python version 2.7 this time and I still get the same error. I know I am using 2.7 because it shows it on the terminal. Also, I tried sending a text to my phone using a simple python program and it worked through twilio. However, the pyhton file that includes more lines of code: wikipedia and wolfram that will get a message and send it back doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Could you upload the code that works (the sending a text to your phone one)? There may be an issue with the way Response is being invoked in the question's code.

Comment: This is the simple code that just sends a message to my phone when I run the python program like this: python filename.py. I didn't need to use 2 terminals or copy a url into twilio.    

from twilio.rest import Client

# Find these values at https://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.api.account.messages.create(to="+12316851234",
                                             from_="+15555555555",
                                             body="Hello there!")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using the latest version of the [Twilio Python module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) then there is no `Response` method. Instead, since you are replying to a message, you need to use the `MessagingResponse` instead.

Try the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia

app = Flask(__name__)

wolf = wolframalpha.Client(wolfram_app_id)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sms():

    message_body = request.form['Body']
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    replyText = getReply(message_body) 
    resp.message('Hi\n\n' + replyText )
    return str(resp)
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your app.

Answer (score 1):

This code is been using Flask for sending message

For installing use:

```
* pip install flask
* pip install twilio

from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods =['POST'])
def sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    response_message = 'Hello {}, You said:{}'.format(number, message_body)
    resp.message(response_message)

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```